# automaticly stop recording when user stops speaking

Tags: android, voice-recording, voice-detection

I want to make an application that records user's voice but turns recording off when user stops to talk. How can I do that?

Comment: Create an event listener that handles the audio input. Once the audio level is below a predetermined threshold, you put the logic to stop the recording.

Comment: @Ahmed, How can I Create an event listener that handles the audio input. Do you have a link on this topic?